# Почему выводит 0 вместо единицы?

Tags: java, c++, полиморфизм

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    void Print() { std::cout << 0; };
};

class Class : public Base {
public:
    void Print() { std::cout << 1; };
};

void Print(Base c) { c.Print(); }

int main() {
    Class *A = new Class();
    Print(*A);
    return 0;
}
```

Почему выводит 0 вместо 1?

На `java` выводит 1:

```
class Base{
    void f(){System.out.print(0);}
}

class Class extends Base{
    void f(){System.out.print(1);}
}

public class Main {

    public static void g(Base x){
        x.f();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        g(new Class());
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в примере на Java имеется опечатка. Я думаю, вы имели в классе Base вывести 0  вместо 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом объявлении функции `Print`

```
void Print(Base c) { c.Print(); }
```

параметр имеет тип `Base`. Соответственно компилятор ищет объявление функции `Print` в классе `Base` и ее вызывает.

В этом вызове функции

```
Print(*A);
```

аргумент `*A`, имеющий тип `Class` преобразуется в объект типа `Base`.

Вы могли бы достичь эффекта аналогичному в программе Java, если бы 1) параметр функции был бы объявлен либо как указатель на объект `Base` либо как ссылка на объект `Base`, а сама функция-член класса `Print` была бы объявлена как виртуальная.

В Java объекты передаются по ссылке, в то время как в вашем примере программы на C++ объекты передаются по значению.

В этом отношении C# располагается "посередине" между C++ и Java. То есть объекты передаются по ссылке, но функции могут быть как виртуальными так и не виртуальными.

**Java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Base
{
    void Print() { System.out.println( 0 ); }
}

class Class extends Base
{
    void Print() { System.out.println( 1 ); }
}

class Ideone
{
    static void Print( Base b ) { b.Print(); }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Print( new Class() );
    }
}
```

Вывод программы

```
1
```

**C#**

```
using System;

class Base
{
    public void Print() { Console.WriteLine( 0 ); }
}

class Class :Base
{
    public new void Print() { Console.WriteLine( 1 ); } 
}

public class Test
{
    static void Print( Base b ) { b.Print(); }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Print( new Class() );
    }
}
```

Вывод программы

```
0
```

Объявление функции виртуальной

```
using System;

class Base
{
    public virtual void Print() { Console.WriteLine( 0 ); }
}

class Class :Base
{
    public override void Print() { Console.WriteLine( 1 ); } 
}

public class Test
{
    static void Print( Base b ) { b.Print(); }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Print( new Class() );
    }
}
```

Вывод программы

```
1
```

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public: 
    void Print() { std::cout << 0 << std::endl; }
};

class Class : public Base
{
public:

    void Print() { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
};


void Print( Base b ) { b.Print(); }

int main() 
{
    Class *A = new Class();

    Print( *A );

    delete A;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы

```
0
```

Объявление функции виртуальной и передача объекта по ссылке

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public: 
    virtual void Print() { std::cout << 0 << std::endl; }
};

class Class : public Base
{
public:

    void Print() override { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
};


void Print( Base &b ) { b.Print(); }

int main() 
{
    Class *A = new Class();

    Print( *A );

    delete A;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы

```
1
```

Объявление функции виртуальной и передача объекта через указатель

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public: 
    virtual void Print() { std::cout << 0 << std::endl; }
};

class Class : public Base
{
public:

    void Print() override { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
};


void Print( Base *b ) { b->Print(); }

int main() 
{
    Class *A = new Class();

    Print( A );

    delete A;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы

```
1
```

Как видно из приведенных примеров, в C# хотя объекты и передаются по ссылке, тем не менее функции должны быть виртуальными, чтобы достичь того же эффекта, что и в Java.

В C++ надо не только объявить функции виртуальными, но и явно передавать объекты либо по ссылке либо через указатель.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что *виртуальность* в C++ по умолчанию не делается. Вам надо явно объявить функцию `Print` виртуальной, и передавать в

```
void Print(Base c)
```

объект по ссылке (или по адресу, но не по значению - это большая ошибка, чреватая к тому же *срезкой*):

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void Print() { std::cout << 0; };
};

class Class : public Base {
public:
    void Print() { std::cout << 1; };
};

void Print(Base& c) { c.Print(); }

int main() {
    Class *A = new Class();
    Print(*A);
    return 0;
}
```

Как `virtual`, достаточно объявить функцию только в базовом классе.

Comment: Поздравляю, у Вас уже 1000 ответов :)

Comment: Спасибо! Даже не знал :)